# Java Generic Type extend multiple classes

Tags: java, generics, interface

How can the type for a generic class extend multiple classes? For example, say I have I generic that I want to be able to take objects that are subclasses of Melons or Berries, but not objects that are subclasses of other subclasses of Fruits?
I was thinking something like

```
public class MyGeneric<T extends Melons & Berries>
```

but this does not work as an interface is expected after the ampersand, not a class. Additionally, online I saw the suggestion to make an interface and have T implement the interface, however I do not understand how to make an interface that specifies classes that can be accepted by a generic.

Answer (score 7):

`&` means **and**. `T extends Melons & Berries` means that T must be some type that extends **both**. You evidently want it to mean **or**. It doesn't. And `<T extends Melons | Berries>` is not legal java syntax. For good reason - that would be useless.

You may think: Wait, you can't extend 2 things. Yes, you can - `extends` in generics refers solely to supertypes; it's like a combination of `extends` and `implements`.

For example:

```
void test(List<? extends Serializable & CharSequence> items) {
}
```

can be invoked by passing a `List<String>`. That's because `String` is a subtype of `Serializable`, and also a subtype of `CharSequence`.

The 'point' of this is that when you get an element from this list, you can treat it as either. Because it's **and** - it's a list of both.

There is no way in java to say: "I want to accept a list of Berries, or a list of melons, but not a list of Apples". The reason there's no way to say that, is because its useless:

- If there's a thing you can do to both melons and berries but not bananas, then whatever it is will have to be defined in an interface of sorts. Perhaps Melons and Berries both implement 'SeededFruit', and Banana doesn't. In that case, just write `List<? extends SeededFruit>` isntead.
- If you just want to use aspects of melons and berries that are shared by all fruit (also bananas), just write `List<? extends Fruit>` - why put up arbitrary restrictions?
- If you want to write `if (x instanceof Melons) doThing1; else if (x instanceof Berries) doThing2;` - java isn't 'meant' for that. There are tons of things java doesn't have that would be really convenient if everybody wrote code like that. But java doesn't have that, will not have that, folks don't usually write their java code like that. Usually if someone does, they're writing very 'bad' code, in the sense that it is overcomplicated and/or hard to maintain and/or hard to adopt in the face of changing requirements, and needlessly so: You could write it differently and avoid those traps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is it bad practice to have an empty interface? The reason I posted this question was to help me with an assignment that specifies for a generic to take 3 different types (though I cannot use their superclass since other classes extend it). However I can just make an interface and have those three classes implement it (the classes are already defined from the instructors code, don't think I am meant to mess with them).

Comment: Not particularly.  There's even a name for it: "flag interfaces". I'd need to know a lot more about your project to determine if using flag interfaces here is dubious or not. All I can say: There are times when making an empty interface is the right move. It may or may not apply to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do is to group the classes using an interface.  Then I use the interface to define the generic class.  See below:

```
interface ForGenerics { }

class Fruit { }
class Melon extends Fruit implements ForGenerics {}
class Berry extends Fruit implements ForGenerics {}
class Apple extends Fruit {}
class MyGeneric<T extends ForGenerics> { }

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyGeneric<Melon> a;
        MyGeneric<Berry> b;
        
        // can't make MyGeneric of Apple
        //  MyGeneric<Apple> c;  
    }
}
```